# Generating random points out of a triangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to generate random points on a given map. I want to avoid having points in the lake area (top right corner). I sort of divided the lake into a rectangle and a triangle. For the rectangle, I could figure out how to avoid having points in there. But, for the triangle (shown with the red line), I couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion? You can find the "Map.png" below the code.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def point_generator(number):
    xlist,ylist = [], []
    for i in range(number):
        x = np.random.uniform(BBox[0],BBox[1])
        y = np.random.uniform(BBox[2],BBox[3])
        while x>-87.8 and y>42.25:
            x = np.random.uniform(BBox[0],BBox[1])
            y = np.random.uniform(BBox[2],BBox[3])
        xlist.append(x); ylist.append(y)
    return(xlist,ylist)

BBox = ((-89.541239, -87.541239,      
         40.773460, 42.498943))
im = plt.imread('Map.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])

plt.plot([-87.8,-87.8],[42.25,42.498943],'-k')
plt.plot([-87.8,-87.541239],[42.25,42.25],'-k')
plt.plot([-87.8,-87.541239],[42.25,41.75],'-r')

xs,ys = point_generator(1500)
plt.plot(xs,ys, '.b')
ax.imshow(im, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal',alpha=0.5)
```

[image: here]

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is to use a circle with just the right radius and position, polygon point intersections can get quite hard!

Comment: @RichardBamford, the lake would be a portion of the circle. That is a possible option to go with. Would you mind going for a coding response?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, see the BBox for the bounds.

Comment: i can't write any detailed python because I'm on a tablet. But you want to have a list of circles where you don't want any points, then all you do is loop over these circles and check the distance from the point, to the circles centre. If this distance is less than the radius of the circle, reject the point.

Comment: I have just updated with the current `point_generator` function.

Comment: @RichardBamford, multiple circles do not seem to be efficient as they will require multiple checks. Instead, I was thinking about having a much larger circle out of the map that a portion of it covers the lake.

Comment: Ok so you are avoiding your square now, just do the same for a triangle... You can do the math for a triangle right?

Comment: @user8028576 actually checking distances is one of the most efficient ways of doing this type of stuff. All you need is to use Pythagoras theorum which is 2 math.pows and 1 math.sqrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underlying color from the image to check if your points are legit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def bBoxPointToColor(px,w,h,BBox,point):
    row = int(((BBox[3]-point[1])/(BBox[3]-BBox[2]))*h)
    col = int(((point[0]-BBox[0])/(BBox[1]-BBox[0]))*w)
    return sum(abs(k[0]-k[1]) for k in zip(px[col,row],(159, 214, 255))) < 10

def point_generator(number,BBox):
    img = Image.open('Chicago.jpg')
    px = img.load()
    xlist,ylist = [], []
    for i in range(number):
        x = np.random.uniform(BBox[0],BBox[1])
        y = np.random.uniform(BBox[2],BBox[3])
        while bBoxPointToColor(px,img.width,img.height,BBox,[x,y]):
            x = np.random.uniform(BBox[0],BBox[1])
            y = np.random.uniform(BBox[2],BBox[3])
        xlist.append(x); ylist.append(y)
    return(xlist,ylist)

BBox = ((-89.541239, -87.541239,      
         40.773460, 42.498943))

im = plt.imread('Chicago.jpg')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])


xs,ys = point_generator(1500,BBox)
plt.plot(xs,ys, '.b')
ax.imshow(im, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal',alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

you can see the issue is that where there is a label on top of the water the point get's drawn on the label... But the benefit is that with this approach you don't have to do custom geometry for new map sections.

[image]

Comment: Color coding could be useful to eliminate the ones on the rivers but doesn't seem to be quite successful on the lake as you pointed (labels).

Comment: I created smaller boxes on the labels and removed those areas as well. I could also solve the problem with color coding but never thought about it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A simple yet correct way of achieving this is by generating random points in the entire surface and then removing the random points that fell in the undesired areas. This way, given that the distribution is uniform in all areas, the remaining distribution is still uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know pandas, but maybe you could get the coordinates `(x1, y1)` of the start point you want the dots to be removed, and then the coordinates of the end point you want `(x2, y2)` and then create a rectangle with the rectangle you created, like `(x1, y1)-(x2, y2)` is one side times `(x2, y2)-(x2, y1)` is the other side you multiply with so you get a rectangle. Half that and you got the coast line showed in your image. The hypotenuse is the actual coastline

- Rectangle: `((x2, y1) - (x1, y1)) * ((x2, y1) - (x2, y2)) = E(rect)`
- Triangle: `E(rect) / 2 = E(triangle)`
- Coastline: `((x2, y1) - (x1, y1)) ** 2 + ((x2, y1) - (x2, y2)) ** 2 = Hypotenuse (Coastline)`
- Graphical representation: [image]

So now you have the surface that you don't want points to appear inside, and the coordinates that make up that surface.